# Use of でもし in this sentence

Tags: grammar

> そんなわけでな、ここでもしあなたが入ってくれれば廃部にならなくてすむんだよ

Right now i have ここでもし as "(i'm) here (with some uncertainty) because..." but it feels like a bit of a stretch.

Answer (score 2):

> ここでもし => here, if

So,

> もしあなたが入ってくれれば

is what you want to focus on.

> If you had joined (the club)

Comment: I wouldn't even say woops. Japanese can be hard to parse, even when you've been working with it for years.